# Ubuntu 18.04.2 Server + Intel VROC Array on a Dell 7920

Tags: dell, ssd, raid

I've been tearing my (limited) hair out for hours now...
We recently received a handful of these shiny new 7920's. They're all configured with dual NVMe SSD's and the appropriate Intel VROC Key dongle/thing.
I've gone into the set up and configured a mirrored array across both SSD's.
VMD Ports are all turned on in the BIOS.

But for the absolute life of me, Ubuntu install will only see the two individual SSD's and not the array.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got around it.
Used the daily: 20190314. 
Had to install using HWE kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Here's are the steps for how to use VROC with Ubuntu:

In the BIOS:

- Enable VMD in BIOS. This was under Advanced -> Intel VMD for me.
- Set your NVMe devices to EFI.
- Set your boot preference to EFI (not dual or legacy).
- Restart.
- If you have the correct setup you should now see an Intel Virtual RAID on CPU option under Advanced. Select that.
- Configure your RAID.
- [Burn](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) the [18.04.2 alternate](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/) installer image to a USB drive.
- Restart again and boot from the USB drive.
- You should have an option at the bottom of the install screen that says something like "Boot and install with HWE kernel."
- If everything is configured correctly, when you get to the drive config screen, you should see this:

[image: Partition Setup screen with RAID option]